# Show user's background image behind my activity

Tags: android, css, image, background

I've been searching around the web for a possible method for getting the user's background behind my activity.

I have some theories(I know it sounds stupid but just for an idea maybe)

I.Get the user's background image as a file and place it in a image viewer

II. make the activity transparent, but i couldn't find any.

Is there any way thats possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second idea is valid. You can create a Translucent activity by adding following to your activity declaration in manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />.
```

In your layout xml you can define the background colour to be transparent.

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

See [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) for more.